# App Installation failed: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

XCode doesnt let me run the iOS-application for a customer on my personal iPhone. While i'm able to create Archives and to push IPAs to Testflight. i am still not able to execute the app directly on my phone.

[image]

There is an "Xcode managed profile" already existing, but it still fails.

[image]

I have added the developer-account of my customer to Xcode. I can select it for "Code signing". The app-ID is the same like it was registered by the customer in his iTunes Connect and Developer-Member-Center-Account.

I have downloaded the provisioning profiles. 
I have added my Device-ID to the Devices in the Developer-account of my customer.

And as already written, i CAN create Archives (via fastlane) and push them to Testflight/AppStore.

Is there any idea how i can test the App on real iOS-Device?

I run several customer accounts on my developer-machine and this one is the first account having such issues.

[image]

Comment: You show that you are using automatic code signing, but also state that you have downloaded the provisioning profile. With automatic code signing, you should have to download any profiles yourself, or add devices to a provisioning profile manually.  It is all done for you in Xcode.  Are you plugging the device into the Mac and trying to build to the device?  Or are you trying to generate an IPA and install it on the device manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, I tried everything mentioned on internet and nothing worked. What worked for me was

1. Go to settings -> General -> Date& Time -> select Set Automatically
2. Delete derived Data from Xcode
3. Clean and Run

This is funny but try this, worked for me.